# onEdit cell - The script works when editing cell B4 in all Sheets

Tags: javascript

Can't figure out how to make it work on Sheet("View") if and only if Cell B4 is edited.

Currently--if I edit cell B4 in any sheet of the workbook, it executes this program.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if( e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "View" ||  
        e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B4'){
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var v = ss.getSheetByName("View");
        var c = ss.getSheetByName("Calculatios");
        var r = c.getRange("M5").getValue();
        v.setActiveSelection(v.getRange("A" + r )); 
        var r = c.getRange("M6").getValue();
        v.setActiveSelection(v.getRange("A" + r )); 
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate()), I wonder if this pattern would work:

```
// Choose a sheet
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];

// Choose a one-cell range on that sheet
var myRange = sheet.getRange('B4');

// Compare that range to your desired cell 
if(e.range == myRange){
  do(stuff);
}
```